# Map array of ints to nested array access

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to dynamically access a nested array using indices which are themselves stored in an array?

The main array/matrix nesting could be variable e.g. 2, 4, 100.

Example:

```
my_array = [
  [[1,  2], [3,   4]],
  [[5,  6], [7,   8]],
  [[9, 10], [11, 12]]
]

my_array.access_using_array([0, 1, 1])
  => 4
```

Answer (score 7):

```
[0, 1, 1].inject(my_array, :fetch)
# => 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby 2.3.0 introduced [a new method called `dig`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-dig) on both `Hash` and `Array` that solves this problem.

It returns `nil` if an element is missing at any level of nesting.

```
my_array.dig(0,1,1)
```